# how to append child view controller in specific view with fixed height

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting problem in size while adding child view controller

XIB veiw : 
[image]

```
class StoreDetailView: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

```
func addChild(vc: UIViewController){
        let v = StoreDetailView(nibName: "StoreDetailView", bundle: nil)
        v.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vc.view.frame.width, height: 80)
        appendAbleView.addSubview(v.view)
        vc.addChild(v)
        heightOfAppendAbleView.constant =  80
        _scrollView.updateContentView()
    }
```

Output what i'm getting: 
[image]

Height is not working here : 
`v.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vc.view.frame.width, height: 80)`

i need to show it in grey view which height 80 `heightOfAppendAbleView.constant =  80`

Answer (score 2):

Only `addChild` is not enough. Let's try this extension

```
extension UIViewController {

    // Add a child view controller, its whole view is embeded in the containerView
    public func addController(controller: UIViewController, containerView: UIView) {
        if let parent = controller.parent, parent == self {
            return
        }
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.frame = CGRect.init(origin: .zero, size: containerView.frame.size)
        controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```